# facebook new feature shared allbums not working

Tags: android, facebook

I have created an album in Facebook added picture to it and set it as a shared album with a friend,he did the same
In Graph API Explorer with the permissions : user_photos , friends_photos among others
the query

"https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"

return a Jason with all my albums, including the one that was set as a shared album  ,BUT NOT the ones that I accepted to be a contributor

now when I try to access the shared album photos

"https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"

I get this  :

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong??? I even try to add all the permission just to test if I am missing same permissions.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: Since this feature is relatively new, maybe it’s not been added to the API yet …?

Comment: Problem fixed by Facebook guys. Now is working. As the owner of the shard album you can see the photos in this album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is actually a bug in Facebook - I ran into this and reported it last week.  Unfortunately, my bug report was disregarded by them; hopefully they will take a second look.  Accessing content in shared albums used to work.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/385336271596379

Comment: I also sent them a report but nothing so far. Is true that they say that they will not read all the reports :(

Comment: Someone else reported this as a bug; you might want to subscribe to it:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/233133173517926

Comment: Dan - FB reports the bug is fixed.  If this solves your problem, perhaps you could mark this question as answered.  Note the limitations in the FB bug thread of discussion.